# Ls command in bash script says 'No such file or directory'

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, ls

The following is the script I am running

```
#$1 - Argument
declare IPATH="sample/"
declare F=$IPATH$1
echo $F
ls $F
```

The input is `./script.sh "Fil*"`

The echo output is -

```
sample/Fil*
```

when I run the command `ls sample/Fil*` I get the required output - A list of files whose name begins with FIL and are in the sample folder as this -

```
sample/File  sample/File1  sample/File2
```

But the script throws the below exception. What am I doing wrong?

```
ls: sample/Fil*: No such file or directory ls: $IPATH: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Something very strange is happening here. The `ls: $IPATH: No such file or directory` part of the error doesn't make any sense -- as the script is written, the `ls` command should never see `$IPATH`, that should've been replaced by its value long before it got near `ls`. Try adding `set -x` at the beginning to enable tracing, and see what that prints about how it's running.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Globs](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob) are not expanded in [quotes](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes). You *can* expand them within scripts, but it's really bad practice (What if someone had a file name containing `*` or `?`? They wouldn't be able to use your script to manipulate it). Best practice is to quote all variable references within scripts, and to pass the actual paths to the scripts:

```
$ mkdir sample
$ touch sample/File1 sample/File2
$ cat script.sh 
#!/bin/sh
F="$1"
echo "$F"
ls "$F"
$ ./script.sh sample/Fil*
sample/File1
sample/File1
```

Or even better, loop over all the files:

```
$ cat script.sh 
#!/bin/sh
for path
do
    echo "$path"
    ls "$path"
done
$ ./script.sh sample/Fil*
sample/File1
sample/File1
sample/File2
sample/File2
```

If you want to hard code part of the path, you could [use `find`](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/blob/master/examples/safe-find.sh) to expand it:

```
while IFS= read -r -d '' -u 9 path
do
    ls -- "$path"
done 9< <( find "sample" -name "$1" -exec printf '%s\0' {} + )
```

Comment: I guess THIS is the problem. But, I need the wild card character. '*'. Let us say that I KNOW that the file names don't contain a '*'. But I don't wish to expand them in the script either. Is there no other way?

Comment: Moreover, I want a part of the path to the file hard coded.

Comment: You are calling the script with the glob, so all you'd need to do is to call it without *quoting* the glob. The shell will take care of expanding it, and as long as you quote it *inside* the script you should have no problems.

Answer (score -1):

ls runs in a separated shell. On that shell, IPATH is not defined, since you have not exported it.

Change "declare" with "export" and it will work.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but it does not seem to help.

Answer (score -1):

Take the *declare* keyword out and it will work. No need of *typing* in Bash:

```
   #!/bin/sh
   IPATH="sample/"
   F=$IPATH$1
   echo $F
   ls $F
```

This will work as you expect.

Comment: That doesn't change anything AFAICT: `ls: cannot access sample/Fil*: No such file or directory`.

Comment: @l0b0 Because it is incorrectly used: first, you are missing the -r/-f/-a... option, then you cannot use a variable in the statement,  $IPATH$1.

Comment: You don't have to use one of those options. Try `declare -p | grep 'declare --'`. `IFS`, `HOSTNAME` and others are declared without a type, which means they are simply strings.

Comment: @l0b0: not true, it works perfectly, just try it.

Comment: @l0b0 I ran the code you see posted above, with call ./script.sh "tst*".

Comment: Actually, it looks like this is a bit tricky. My `/bin/sh` is Bash...